# Flutter changing color in ParagraphStyle

Tags: flutter, mobile

I'm currently working on a project and i'm using ParagraphStyle and i can't find anywhere how to change the default (white) color.

I searched everywhere and can't find a solution. This is my ParagraphStyle code

```
final textStyle = ParagraphStyle(
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
      fontSize: fontSize + 2,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
    );
```

Comment: this should work https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ParagraphBuilder/pushStyle.html (not tested though...)

Comment: i tried it but i keep getting this error The argument type 'TextStyle (where TextStyle is defined in C:\srcflutter\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\painting\text_style.dart)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'TextStyle (where TextStyle is defined in C:\srcflutter\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\text.dart)'.dartargument_type_not_assignable
text_style.dart(472, 7): TextStyle is defined in C:\srcflutter\flutter\packages\flutter\lib\src\painting\text_style.dart
text.dart(1616, 7): TextStyle is defined in C:\srcflutter\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\ui\text.dart

Comment: btw I am assuming that you use it for `Canvas` painting, if so, why not to use `TextPainter`?

Comment: this is because there are two `TextStyle` classes, see https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextStyle-class.html and notice "see also" section - in short one is from `painting` library and another from `ui`

Comment: does TextPainter do the same job?

Comment: yes, and is much more simpler for non complex cases - when creating you only need to pass `textDirection` and `text` of course

Comment: i just changed from Canvas to TextPainter and i fixed it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: sure, your welcome, and is it indeed easier?

Comment: yeah a lot easier for the thing i am trying to make

Answer (score 0):

You can use this following code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final fontSize = 16.0;

    final textStyle = TextStyle(
      fontSize: fontSize + 2,
      fontWeight: FontWeight.w500,
      color: Colors.blue, // Set your desired color here
    );

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: RichText(
            text: TextSpan(
              text: 'Your Text Here',
              style: textStyle,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```